# Create multiple Windows same way?

Tags: windows, windows-10

I have about 20 new `notebook` PC by HP without anything set (Windows 10 Pro).
I would like to make a `PC kitting` - set every `PC` the same way
(same settings, same installed programs, same bookmarks, same default apps), without need to do this 20 times. Is there a way or tool to make it once and copy all this setting to remaining `PCs`?
Thanks

Comment: You can achieve what you want with a custom .wim Windows image and DISM.  Microsoft has fully documented the process.  If you are stuck on a specific step we can help out, otherwise, the process of creating a custom Windows install image is while not difficult is indeed complex.

Comment: The above comment is correct, you can achieve this with `dism`, however there is one caveat and it isn't small: the laptops in question must be of the same make and model and have exactly the same hardware, otherwise it won't work.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install one PC with the configuration that you need. When you come up with the correct and finished configuration (ready to use), you can create a ghost image. When your ghost image is ready, you can then clone (restore) it to the other computers as they have the same configurations (driver, third-party software...).

There are many softwares and method for creating a ghost image of a computer. Examples are provided [here](https://help.symantec.com/cs/GSS3.2/GSS_GUIDE/v115380298_v122754873/Creating-a-disk-image?locale=EN_US) or [that](https://www.osalt.com/ghost). The best ressource on this might be [How to make a disk image and restore from it later?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/19901/how-to-make-a-disk-image-and-restore-from-it-later) in my humble opinion. You can use it to create an image of the first installation and then retore it on the other PC.

Comment: doesn't this create the "same" windows, meaning a `licence key` will be same?

Comment: You may for instance not activate your current license on the original ghost image and the only operation you have to do is to activate the license for each machine after ghosting them. Inspiration and idea on a single license may be found (https://community.spiceworks.com/how_to/124056-reimaging-rights-for-windows-10-licensing-how-to)

Comment: I have licences already activated :(

Comment: If you mean that all the machine have their licenses already activated, currently. Nothing prevents you from reactivating them after ghosting. You only need the license information

Comment: thanks, I will give it a try!

Comment: You may delete activation of windows by mounting the hidden partition and renaming the activ.txt file which is in it. The hidden partition is about 100megs.
Then when the systems are ghosted, you reactivate them one by one

Answer (score 0):

Since we're talking about Windows here specifically, I would suggest you drop a look on Microsoft Endpoint Configuration Manager: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/mem/configmgr/core/understand/introduction.

The requirement that you've got is quite a common norm in IT, where they would need to configure the laptops/PC/notebooks of all their employees centrally.

There are many other tools like these and they go by the tag Endpoint configuration managers. You may take a look on others as well and see what fits the best to your requirement.

Answer (score -1):

Here's what I found https://www.tribuscomputer.com/deploy-software-installs-to-multiple-computers-all-at-once/
It will help install the same package of apps on different computers at once.
And this one is to sync the settings https://www.pcmag.com/news/how-to-sync-windows-10-settings-across-multiple-pcs

Answer (score -2):

First of all complete installation in single laptop like Operating system  and software
after that install AOMEI Backupper Standard 6.4
and you get option os and software backup in usb pendrive image bootable
and get restore that multi laptop and pc..